# C# - Reordering controls by z-index in Panel

Tags: c#, user-controls, panel, picturebox

I have a Panel with a **PictureBox** with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`. I need to dynamically add controls to the Panel, but they must stay above the PictureBox.

This is easy within the Designer, but when I do this programmatically, neither SetChildIndex(), BringToFront() or SendToBack() work.

I have to use PictureBox, I can't just set Panel.BackgroundImage because it's glitchy.

Comment: If the controls are all members of the Panel's controls collection they are siblings.  There is no concept of in front of or "above" another control.

Comment: But I can put any control "above" the PictureBox in the Designer just fine. Why doesn't it work in code?

Comment: You could try messing around with visible()

Comment: BringToFront() or SendToBack()  do work. Or you can do ctl.Parent = pbox;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fount this to be an issue with the order of the controls in the panel in the design.cs

Remove the controls from the panel and add them in the correct order.

```
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 238);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

[image: button under piturebox]

```
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 238);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Kinda doesn't makes sense at first because pictureBox1 is added later, but stays "beneath" button1.

Answer (score 1):

Once you add your dynamic control to the `Controls` find it and `BringToFront` like as follows:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox
{
    Location = new Point(100, 100),
    Name = "Textbox1"
};

this.Controls.Add(tb);

var contr = Controls.Find("Textbox1", true)[0];
contr.BringToFront();
```

Alternatively, once you add new dynamic control. Apply `SendToBack` to the `PictureBox`.

```
  pictureBox1.SendToBack();
```

[image: lion]